# ThreeTen: no suitable method found (while running mvn clean install)

Tags: java, maven, java-8, java-7

I am trying to run mvn clean install on Mac.
We have a project under Java7, with some things used from Java8(like dates, which uses ThreeTen project).
While going into preferences.app on Mac, I see that my path links to Java8, more precisely:
My java version is

```
java version "1.8.0_161"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

Could that be a problem of the following error?

```
[ERROR] incompatible types: java.time.ZonedDateTime cannot be converted to org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime
```

and others, all mentioning the same **ThreeTen**

```
[ERROR]     method com.opengamma.analytics.financial.instrument.annuity.AnnuityCouponIborDefinition.from(org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime,org.threeten.bp.Period,double,com.opengamma.analytics.financial.instrument.index.IborIndex,boolean,com.opengamma.financial.convention.calendar.Calendar) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (argument mismatch; org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime cannot be converted to org.threeten.bp.Period)
```

If so, how shall I specify JDK of the Java7, which I downloaded? I have downloaded Java7, and now have Java6,7,8 here:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

Here is how the **AnnuityCouponIborDefinition** looks like this
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGjtQ.png)

Additionally Target runtime Apache Tomcat is not defined (it is irrelevant, as I want to run only JUNIT tests) and Maven has some problems.

Comment: To my understanding, it does not look like a Java 8 problem. `java.time` is found but it looks like you try to assign a `org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime` to a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` which seems wrong because `org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime` does not extend or implement `java.time.ZonedDateTime`. Can you show the relevant lines of code?

Comment: imho, you have a problem with your imports.

Comment: Your problem is with your code, *you need to post the line giving you the error*.  It's not the java version or anything to do with Maven.  If you want to change the JRE that Maven uses, set JAVA_HOME to the path to the JDK.  That will not fix your problem.

Comment: dear @ArnaudDenoyelle, mikeb. I wanted to see the line that gives the error as you suggested, but after I created new workspace and did mvn clean install -X I see the build successful. Maybe it is Eclipse magic...